# Running Powershell scripts pushed from AD GPO as admin on domain computers

Tags: active-directory, powershell, group-policy, startup-scripts, administrative-privileges

Needed some help getting a simple task done at work.

I have about 30 machines in my work domain that i want to run a power-shell script on at startup.
I have created a GPO that runs the script on all machines at startup and all machines have the GPO applied successfully.
The power-shell script is supposed to lookup a service on the machine and if it finds it, it starts it up and that's it. If the service does not exist, the script continues running and copies a file stored on a shared folder in the domain into the machine and then creates the service then starts it up.

**MY PROBLEM:** the script does not run automatically on all machines.

After some troubleshooting i found out that running scripts on the machines with the domain user logged in is not allowed and when i try to run the script manually on each machine i get an error that says running scripts is disabled, so i created a GPO that enables running scripts on the machines by enabling the Turn on Script Execution Policy. Regardless the script did not do it's job after restarting the machines and i still get the same error when i try manually.
Then i tried to run the script manually as admin on the machines and the script performed it's work perfectly.

Also tried adding the following two commands -based on suggestions from other people having similar problems- in the beginning of the power-shell script, the first to elevate the script to run as admin and the second to allow running scripts on the machine and it did not make any change.
COMMAND #1: start-process powershell –verb runAs
COMMAND #2: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

**Currently the number of device is going to get close to 200 and i need to get this script to run as admin on all machines from the applied GPO. Waiting to read some solutions from you shortly**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a Startup script or a Logon script in your GPO? Also you should set the execution policy before executing the script...

Answer (score 1):

Try this implementation approach:

- Use GPO to run your script via Task Scheduler as SYSTEM, not a user
- Give Domain Computers AD group access to a share for the script to be able to copy file from it